# Flutter GetX Get.find() returning null only at the first time

Tags: flutter, controller, flutter-getx

I am following uber_clone project on youtube. What the difference thing between tutorial and mine is that I am using GetX. I am facing the problem that I am getting null value for the first time when I use data from other controller.

`dropOffLocation` takes data from SeachController and I am tring to save dropOff data to firebase, but for the first time when I save the dropOff data it is null, so in firebase database stores null data of logitude and latitude of dropOff, but after I press cancel button that execute `cancelRideRequest' method, and then, search destination, and then press request button that execute` saveRideRequest`, finally I can store dropoff data in firebase database.

Why does it happen, how can I solve it?

```
// HomeController
  void saveRideRequest() {
    Rx<Address> dropOffLocation = SearchController.to.dropOffLocation;

    rideRequestRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Requests").push();

    var pickUp = pickUpLocation.value;
    var dropOff = dropOffLocation.value;
    print(dropOff.longitude);

    Map pickUpLocMap = {
      "latitude": pickUp.latitude.toString(),
      "logitude": pickUp.longitude.toString(),
    };

    Map dropOffLocMap = {
      "latitude": dropOff.latitude.toString(),
      "logitude": dropOff.longitude.toString(),
    };

    Map rideInfoMap = {
      "driver_id": "waiting",
      "payment_method": "cash",
      "pickup": pickUpLocMap,
      "dropoff": dropOffLocMap,
      "created_at": DateTime.now().toString(),
      "rider_name": userCurrentInfo!.name,
      "rider_phone": userCurrentInfo!.phone,
      "pickup_address": pickUp.placeName,
      "dropoff_address": dropOff.placeName,
    };

    rideRequestRef!.set(rideInfoMap);
  }


// ...
// ...

 void cancelRideRequest() {
    rideRequestRef!.remove();
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will get this error until a `instance` of your `controller` is created basically the reason is **Get.find()** finds a instance of already `initiated controller` in your `project tree` if your `controller` has not been `initialized` then it will simply `return` a null value. So before using **Get.find()** you have to create `instance` of your `controller` by using **Get.put(YOUR_CONTROLLER);** then you are free to use **Get.find()**.

Comment: Behind the scene, I added Get.lazyPut(() => SearchController()); when I press request button to initialize SearchController, isn't it the same as what you answered? and I added Get.put(SearchController()); above `Rx<Address> dropOffLocation = SearchController.to.dropOffLocation;` as you guided, but it still doesn't work 

Comment: Get.lazyPut is used to lazily load a dependency so that it will be instantiated only when is used and Get.put initiates your dependency even if there's no use for now. Also are you using Get.put and Get.find in the same class or file?

Comment: First you have to use Get.put() after the controller initialize successfully fully then you can use Get.find()

Comment: I used Get.put just right above `Rx<Address> dropOffLocation = SearchController.to.dropOffLocation;` which is Get.find. And, it is in the same `saveRideRequest` in the class and file, `HomeController`. Shouldn't it be used like this? 
I also tried to use Get.put in a different file and class in a `request` button, and it is also the result, showing `null` at the first time and if I redo it it shows the right data.

Comment: I used Get.lazyPut when I navigate to search page, so I replaced this with Get.put and added `permanent: true`, then it seems working which means I can store dropOff location data in firebase database, `BUT!` since the controller is `permanent: true`, `onClosed` is never called, so`TextEditingController` never get disposed, then the previous location string to search remains... Finally, I intentionally assign constant value which is empty string to `TextEditingController.text`..... Do you think this kind of approach is okay? This is working as I wanted, but it seems something is wrong...

Comment: I think you need to share your code too but for TextController you can use .clear() method to clear your TextController

Comment: If you are having issues related to initialization of controller then just put you controller on dashboard or main screen then .find() will work from starting of the app

Comment: https://github.com/realryankim/flutter-uber-clone  : it is my repository, and could you please check my last commit if you have time please, and give me any advice about the issue, especially about `Get.put(SearchController());` and `Get.delete<SearchController>(force: true);` parts

Comment: I'll check  and let you know